# What does the getId() return of an inflated view?

Tags: android, switch-statement, layout-inflater

Hee Guys,

I'm currently having an issue with a switch case that should case my inflatedView (I have 3 different layouts which, depends on the showing Fragment, will be inflated in my MenuBar).

Currently my switch case is looking like this:

```
switch(inflatedView.getId()){
        case R.layout.menu_title_only:
            break;
        case R.layout.menu_segment_controller:
            break;
    }
```

However it does not proc the desired case when it is for sure inflated.

I know View.getId() returns the android:id of this View, but what if this view is inflated? Which id will it return then?

```
public void inflateMenu(BaseFragment frag, String color){
    this.color = color;
    // Clear Views
    menu.removeAllViews();

    // Check which menu to inflate
    Class<? extends Fragment> FragClass;
    FragClass = frag.getClass();
    if(FragClass == LocationsFragment.class || FragClass == MustDoFragment.class){
        menu.removeAllViews();
        inflatedView = activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.menu_segment_controller, menu);
    } else if(FragClass == HomeFragment.class) {
        inflatedView = activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.menu_title_only, menu);
    } else if(FragClass == ButtonFragment.class || FragClass == NewsFragment.class ||
            FragClass == EventsFragment.class || FragClass == MapFragment.class) {
        inflatedView = activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.menu_title_only, menu);
    } else if(FragClass == ViewLocationFragment.class){
        inflatedView = activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.menu_share_favorite, menu);
    } else {
        inflatedView = activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.menu_title_only, menu);
    }
    setListeners();
}
```

setListeners(), will use the switch case.

Comment: did you run your application ?

Comment: Yes, I did run my application.

Comment: Show how you inflated your view?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

getId() will return the id of the top-level View in your layout. So for e.g. if you have a layout file like this in *my_layout.xml*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/top_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/testimage"
        android:layout_width="500dp"
        android:layout_height="500dp"
        android:src="@drawable/image1" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Then getId() for the inflated view will be equal to `R.id.top_layout` and NOT `R.layout.my_layout`.

However, you can set ids, so if you add this code:

```
inflatedView = activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.menu_segment_controller, menu);
inflatedView.setId(R.layout.menu_segment_controller);
```

Then getId() will return `R.layout.menu_segment_controller`

Comment: I'll try the setId(), because the R.id.top_layout is not working.